# How to set up the login screen to ask for keyboard layout

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, gdm

I just upgraded my distro, now it no longer has a menu to set the keyboard layout in the login screen (gdm). Previously a user could select there icon, then change the keyboard layout (it would also remember previous choice of this user), and then type in password and continue the session, using there selected layout.

I have users using dvorak and qwerty uk.

I have looked at various pages of help on the subject of configuring gdm, but have found nothing on keyboard layouts.

Can you help with how to add the keyboard layout selector?

Comment: What did you upgrade from and to?

Comment: from debian 6 (wheezy) to debian 7 (squeeze)

Comment: @richard Debian 6 is "Squeeze", Debian 7 is "Wheezy".